# How to force a "sync CodeDeploy" on EC2 machine with agent?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I have a machine with a Cloud-Init initialization script that is installing the CodeDeploy agent.
I would like the during the initialization I could start some services deployed with the package.
Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you launch your instance with AutoScaling, you can configure CodeDeploy to automatically deploy to them. You still need to do what you are doing now and install the CodeDeploy agent.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/auto-scaling-integ.html